# AfterTestRun hook not working Is there any work around without upgrading the version

Tags: selenium, nunit, specflow

I am using Nunit 2.6.4  with specflow.Nunit 1.1.1 version.Please suggest if there is any work around without upgrading. If not please let me know the first version where this fix is available, as i have limitation in upgrading it to latest version.

Answer (score 0):

The AfterTestRun hook is normally called when the step assembly is unloaded. This does not work on all test runners and NUnit 2.6 is one of them.

You need this extension for NUnit: https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/blob/master/Installer/NuGetPackages/SpecFlow.NUnit.Runners/SpecFlowNUnitExtension.cs

Download and add this file to your test project and the hook should be called.